# How can I make a question using passive verbs with prepositions?

Tags: grammar, phrasal-verbs, passive-voice

I wonder how i can make a question using verbs with prepositions especially when they are in passive voice.

For example, I have a sentence like below:
An appointment is required for the service.

And I made this normal sentence into a question:
For which service is an appointment required?
I understand that this sentence is correct.

But, here i suddenly came up with one idea.
Could you let me know if the sentence below is correct or not? If not, why is the sentence incorrect?

“Which service is an appointment required for?”

Comment: Yes, that is fine. It is probably more natural / informal than your first version. (There are a small number of ignorant people who wrongly claim you should not end a question with a proposition. Ignore them.)

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick, kind answer. It really helped me a lot.

Comment: Yes, it's correct. Alternatively (and rather more attractively, you might say: **For which service is an appointment required**. Final prepositions have a habit of getting lost: **What are you going outside before you've made the tea and cleared the table as I asked you to for?**

Answer (score 1):

As said in the comments, there is nothing wrong with ending a sentence with a preposition. (See ["Ending a Sentence With a Preposition"](https://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/ending-a-sentence-with-a-preposition) by Mignon Fogarty.)

Between your first and second examples, the second seems more natural to me:

> Which service is an appointment required for?

In general, rephrasing a sentence to avoid ending it with a preposition results in it sounding more awkward.

---

On the other hand, the active voice often sounds more natural than the passive voice. (Although, that's not always the case.)

While I suspect you were deliberately trying to come up with a passive-voice question in this case, it would be more natural to hear something like:

> Which services require an appointment?